# Having trouble constructing the proper linq-to-xml query

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm new to linq and I'm having trouble writing a query that pulls back the data I'm looking for.  The xml file has orders, each order has purchase order info and products, each prouct has its own elements and descendants.  I need to query all the orders and their descendants into one colletion but for some reason the linq query syntax is very counter-intuitive to me.

Here's a truncated sample of my xml

```
<fulfillment>
   <orders>
      <order>
         <isbulk>true</isbulk> 
         <purchaseorder>
            <id>Acme Inustries</id> 
            <quantity>15</quantity> 
         </purchaseorder>
         <items>
            <item>
               <prods>
                  <prod>
                     <seq>1</seq> 
                     <issuetype>NEW</issuetype> 
                     <loop>
                        <proxy>xyz123</proxy> 
                        <servicecode>55</servicecode> 
                     </loop>
                  </prod>
                  <prod>
                     <seq>2</seq> 
                     <issuetype>NEW</issuetype> 
                     <loop>
                        <proxy>abc987</proxy> 
                        <servicecode>121</servicecode> 
                     </loop>
                  </prod>
               </prods>
            </item>
         </items>
      </order>
      <order>
         <isbulk>true</isbulk> 
         <purchaseorder>
            <id>ABC Co</id> 
            <quantity>10</quantity> 
         </purchaseorder>
         <items>
            <item>
               <prods>
                  <prod>
                     <seq>1</seq> 
                     <issuetype>NEW</issuetype> 
                     <loop>
                        <proxy>xyz456</proxy> 
                        <servicecode>998</servicecode> 
                     </loop>
                  </prod>
                  <prod>
                     <seq>2</seq> 
                     <issuetype>NEW</issuetype> 
                     <loop>
                        <proxy>abc654</proxy> 
                        <servicecode>664</servicecode> 
                     </loop>
                  </prod>
               </prods>
            </item>
         </items>
      </order>
   </orders>
</fulfillment>
```

My objects look a bit like this:

```
public class order
{
    public bool IsBulk { get; set; }

    public PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder();
    public List<prod> ListOfProds = new List<prod>();
}

public class prod
{
    public string Seq { get; set; }
    public string IssueType { get; set; }

    public string Proxy { get; set; }
    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

So I've been working on a query for the best part of a day and just can't seem to get it right.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
List<order> orderlist = new List<order>();
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);

var list = (from myOrder in xmlDoc.Descendants("order")             
select new       
{
   linq_orderIsBulk = Convert.ToBoolean(myOrder.Element("isbulk").Value),

   linq_purchaseOrderID = myOrder.Element("purchaseorder").Element("id").Value,
   linq_purchaseOrderQuantity = myOrder.Element("purchaseorder").Element("quantity").Value,

   prodlist = myOrder.Element("items").Element("item").Element("prods").Elements("prod").Select(e => new
   {                
      Linq_seq = e.Element("seq").Value,
      Linq_IssueType = e.Element("issuetype").Value,

      Linq_proxy = e.Element("loop").Element("proxy").Value,
      Linq_serviceCode = e.Element("loop").Element("servicecode").Value
   }).ToList()
});
```

//do code to put the collection in list into List orderlist

But when I do this, I seem to end up getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the subquery.  When I comment out the Linq_proxy and Linq_serviceCode lines, I get results but not the right ones.  When I loop through list and grab a single order then look at the prodlist for that order, the count is the total amount of prods for that file (4) instead of the 2 for that order.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you want `xmlDoc.Elements("order")`.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  It's "loop".  EDITED

Comment: jrummell, I tried that and now list.Count() = 0

Comment: I just tried your query out in LINQPad and got neither the exceptions nor the count problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran this, and it works fine:

```
var orders = new List<order>(
    from myOrder in xmlDoc.Descendants("order")
    let purchaseOrder = myOrder.Element("purchaseorder")
    select new order {
        IsBulk = Convert.ToBoolean(myOrder.Element("isbulk").Value),
        PurchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder {
            ID = purchaseOrder.Element("id").Value,
            Quantity = purchaseOrder.Element("quantity").Value
        },
        ListOfProds = new List<prod>(
            from product in myOrder.Descendants("prod")
            let loop = product.Element("loop")
            select new prod
            {                
                Seq = product.Element("seq").Value,
                IssueType = product.Element("issuetype").Value,
                Proxy = loop.Element("proxy").Value,
                ServiceCode = loop.Element("servicecode").Value
            }
        )
    }
);
```

Notice that you can project a collection directly into objects of your type, so you don't have to have code later on to create your orders collection.

Comment: Not sure why the old one didn't work but I just never got good results.  However, your new query is awesome anyway.  Works great.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to add line number error checking? So if the data is bad, it will return the line number that caused the problem (or the last good line)?  I supposed I could brute-force my way through it by adding linenumber properties to the collection but that doesn't seem like a good way.

Comment: Unfortunately no. That would be a fantastic amount of help, no? But I have seen that if you use the step debugger and "step in" to the LINQ's execution, you can usually see the portion of the query that is getting the exception.

Comment: Which is great for debugging but for this project, the query is going to be part of a larger custom object that will be called by the code and returns the records.  And the boss wants to be able to see the line numbers.  So I loath to do this but I might just have to include like a prodlinenumber (for each of the members) to my object.  sigh.